# Highstock Chart - I want the chart to start at position 0% (beginning) on the x-axis

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have tried various permutations of the xAxis setting for the chart - wanting to make the chart start at the start of the x-axis (left most).  In the following setup, the x-axis start on Jul 1st (I don't need that) - but the first timestamp in my data is for July 10th.

```
xAxis: {
            crosshair: {
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                zIndex: 2,
            },
            min: timeStamp,
            type: 'datetime',
            ordinal: false,
            startOnTick: true,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0.025,
            minTickInterval: 28 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            labels: {
                format: '{value:%b %Y}',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '14px !important',
                },
            },
        },
```

This generates the following picture

[image]

How can I move the first data points (July 10th) to appear/line up at the of the x-axis (position 0% of the x-axis) - along the y-axis?

Comment: a stackblitz with minimal code can help us resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tickPositioner` function to arrange the tick the way you want:

```
xAxis: {
    crosshair: {
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        zIndex: 2
    },
    startOnTick: true,
    tickPositioner: function(){
        var positions = [],
            tickInterval = 28 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            i = this.dataMin;

        for (; i <= this.dataMax; i+= tickInterval) {
            positions.push(i);
        }

        return positions;
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        format: '{value:%e %b %Y}',
        style: {
            fontSize: '14px'
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mn75610L/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Genius!  Thanks a lot.  This is the solution

Comment: ppotaczek. You solved my main problem - however, the labels on the xAxis are not aligned.  The data points shift to the left as I wanted, but the labels on the xAxis stay in the same place.  Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: Hi Geoff Kabule, You need to adapt the `tickInterval` variable to the x-value points interval or modify the function: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j8ayhgu0/